# How to modify Json body before receiving?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I receive different objects set from the API. Each response have a follow structure:

```json
items:[
 {
  user_id:1,
  tags: {..}
 },
{..}
]
```

The problem is that I do not want so unuseful and not readable structure.
I mean, all my methods (I use `Retrofit` library) must have some next signature:

```
Call<UserRepresantation>...
Call<RepoRepresentation>...
```

instead

```
Call<List<Users>>
Call<List<Repos>>
```

And also I have to use additional entities every time:

```
class UserRepresentation{
  List<Users> items;
}
```

The Retrofite has possibility to use different converters for the serialization, for example:

```java
Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(stckUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson())) < --- converter applying
                .build();
```

As I understand I can use `JsonSeializer` to configure such behavior, but I can't figure out in which way. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

---

So, in the simple words:

we have a `response`:

```json
items:[
 {
  user_id:1,
  tags: {..}
 },
{..}
]
```

And we need to receive:

```
List<Users> = gson.fromJson(respose, User.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to write a [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) which performs the unwrapping when asked to deserialize any `List<User>` and `List<Repo>`, or in general for any `List`. However, the problem with this is that it would also apply to any nested lists of these types, for example when your `User` class has a field `List<Repo> repos` then that adapter factory would also try to unwrap its value, and fail.

So a more reliable solution might be to implement a `TypeAdapterFactory` which keeps track of whether it is currently being used to deserialize the top-level value and in that case unwrap / flatten the data. If not used for the top-level value it could simply let the other registered adapter factories handle the data:

```java
class FlatteningTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    public static final FlatteningTypeAdapterFactory INSTANCE = new FlatteningTypeAdapterFactory();

    private FlatteningTypeAdapterFactory() { }

    /** Tracks whether this is a nested call to this factory */
    private static final ThreadLocal<Boolean> isNestedCall = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        // Only handle top-level value, for nested calls let other factory handle it
        // Uses Boolean.TRUE.equals to handle case where value is `null`
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(isNestedCall.get())) {
            return null;
        }

        TypeAdapter<T> delegate;
        isNestedCall.set(true);
        try {
            delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        } finally {
            isNestedCall.remove();
        }

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                in.beginObject();
                String name = in.nextName();
                if (!name.equals("items")) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected member name: " + name);
                }

                T value;
                // While using delegate adapter also set isNestedCall in case delegate looks up
                // another adapter dynamically while its `read` method is called
                isNestedCall.set(true);
                try {
                    value = delegate.read(in);
                } finally {
                    isNestedCall.remove();
                }

                in.endObject();
                return value;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

You would then have to register it with a `GsonBuilder` before constructing the `GsonConverterFactory`:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(FlatteningTypeAdapterFactory.INSTANCE)
    .create();
```

Note that the code above has not been extensively tested; there might be bugs or corner cases where it does not work correctly.

Comment: Thanks, however, I found a solution, I'll try yours and accept if it works correctly. Your solution seems more flexible.